# How to do HTTP Tunneling over SSH for specific URLs on Chrome?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, http-tunneling

I connect to my university server via ssh using the following command:

```
ssh myid@cs.bu.edu
```

Another server, `hidden.bu.edu` is firewalled in `cs.bu.edu`. To access `hidden.bu.edu`, I have added the following lines in my `~/.ssh/config` in my home laptop.

```
Host hidden.bu.edu
    ProxyCommand ssh myid@cs.bu.edu -W %h:%p
```

Now I can just do `ssh myid@hidden.bu.edu` to log into `hidden.bu.edu` from my home laptop.

Now I have another HTTP hidden server `webhidden.bu.edu` which is only accessible from inside `cs.bu.edu`. I can use a VPN to access `webhidden.bu.edu` in Google Chrome, but I do not want to use any VPN software. Is it possible to tunnel `webhidden.bu.edu` in Google Chrome through `cs.bu.edu` over ssh, just like I use a proxy for ssh-ing `hidden.bu.edu`.

I know HTTP Tunneling might work, but I want to just enter `webhidden.bu.edu` in Google chrome and it should tunnel over my ssh `config`. This is also what happens in case of `git` server, just by adding the above lines in `~/.ssh/config`. Is there something possible for HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `~/.ssh/config` I create a proxy:

```
Host buproxy
  HostName csa3.bu.edu
  User soham1 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  DynamicForward 9500
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h:%p
```

I add the following for a proxy command on my shell:

```
alias proxy-on='/usr/bin/ssh -fN buproxy'
alias proxy-check='/usr/bin/ssh -O check my-proxy'
```

Then I use `proxy-on` command on a shell terminal to turn on the proxy.

After that, I use [SwitchyOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif?hl=en) Google Chrome Extension to set up a SOCKS5 localhost:9500 proxy to browse any webpages via this ssh-proxy. I setup wildcard characters in SwitcyOmega to autoswitch particular websites such as `*.acm.org, *.ieee.org`.